# monitor iis vhosts bandwidth usage with cacti

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, bandwidth, cacti

I am trying to monitor how much bandwidth is being used by websites(vhosts) on my iis (7.5) machine. on a per site basis. Is their a cacti plugin or configuration guide that i can use to monitor this. My cacti setup is running on a ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to monitor upstream bandwidth usage for individual IIS websites is by counting the sum of the "sc-bytes" value for each request in the IIS W3SVC logfiles.

There are several approaches to this, eg. generic log parsers, bulk importing logs to a database, direct read and aggregation from the daily logs, etc.

I don't think there is a cacti plugin available but these custom user submitted graph templates might point you in the right directions: http://forums.cacti.net/about12464.html

You might wan't to check out the [IIS Log Analyzer](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1864), a comprehensive extension of the IIS log parser. You could set up a scheduled task to run the analyzer, and sum up the daily traffic flow in any txt format for cacti to read.